# Practicing interview questions and want to know how to approach this one aka algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Saw this as an interview question would want to know the correct way to break this down that way I can understand the thought process and code it myself for practice. Also any advice on how to break down a problem.

"There is a n * n square board, there’s a new kind of game which is played on this board. there are pieces on the board which can only move horizontal and vertical any number of squares until it encounters an opponent piece, when it does so, it replaces the opponent piece at that position and the turn alternates. The input will contain a n * n matrix with 1,2 and 0 in the cells. ‘1’ denotes your pieces, ‘2’ denotes opponent pieces, and ‘0’ denotes free space. One of your pieces has fallen from the board and neither you nor your opponent remember its original position, so you collectively decide that you can place it anywhere you want to, so its upto you to place it at a position where you can maximize the number of opponent pieces you can cut. Output the x and y coordinates of such position. If multiple positions exists, output anyone."

Comment: What is considered a single move? It's unclear.

Comment: You can move up or down, left or right. It's like checkers that you can hop over an enemy and capture the piece. You can capture multiple enemies as well.

Comment: Will I get one more move after cutting the each opponent piece?

Comment: From the description you don't `hop over`, rather you replace the enemy piece with yours. The way I understand it, the best place(s) to put the piece is where there's an enemy piece as the first piece in all four allowed directions from that coordinate. Next best is three enemy pieces, and so on.